# ehcache theoretical queries.I have a small web application.we have not embedded ehcache intially.but there is recent requirement

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a small web application.we have not embedded ehcache intially.but there is recent requirement to implement ehcache in mid of application.though i am new to ehcache still configured it my app. there are certain question please try to answer this.

1. Which  is better way to annotate the class a) DAO b) Services (i have implemented in DAO?
2. @Cacheable, @CacheEvict @cacheput 
   for above annotation what we need to concentrate on for my crud queries..

I mean do we check return type or parameter for that method to specify @annotation part.

please suggest some online tutorial related to my issue.

Comment: please suggest some online tutorial related to my issue.

Comment: Suppose a person is logged in with his credential and execute a query on some his search criteria. in between other person logged in ..and execute with his search criteria . what would be the  search result of both user how cache handle this situation.

Comment: please help implementing custom key in my application. please help step by step or suggest tutorial that define steps in easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put my little "it depends" in here. About point one.

1. Caching as high as you can is the most efficient
2. Caching as low as you can is the most reusable

So, if you cache at the DAO level, you have higher chances that the cache result be used by multiple services.

However, if you cache at the web service level, then your user will get a blazing fast response.

So, it depends. Pick whatever fits your needs. Service per service.